# Hiding "Calculated Area" information in a Shape item in Visio 2016

Tags: microsoft-visio

In Visio 2016, when inserting a "Space" shape (from the "Walls, Shell and Structure" stencil in the "Maps and Floor Plan" category) the inserted and auto-sized shape shows by default the name "Office" (which is editable through the "Shape Data" menu) and the "Calculated Area" field value.
How can I hide the later (i.e. the "Calculated Area" value) which is useless to me?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the shape and select **Set Display Options**. Select the **Spaces** tab and you will see four label drop-down boxes, one of which will have **Calculated area** set. Change this to **Disabled**.